# Representing resources in RESTful API

Tags: rest

I have a database of surveys responses and I'm trying to build a RESTful API to expose this data. API should be able to return the following information:

1. Available surveys
2. Questions
3. Answers
4. Report (sum of responses for every type of answer per survey question)

I have a problem with identifying how should the resources be structured in this case.

For surveys, questions and responses it's fairly simple:

```
GET /surveys
GET /questions // filter by surveyId possible
GET /responses // filter by questionId and SurveyId possible
```

What would be the best approach to fit the reports in this structure? Do I set up a separate route, e.g.:

```
GET /reports/responses-by-question?surveyId=1
```

or do I add it as next level in the responses path? E.g.

```
GET /responses/by-question?surveyId=1
```

Or do I get this completely wrong and there's some better approach?

Comment: How about surveys/1/reports to get all reports for a survey?

Comment: I was thinking about it, but the report calculates the responses, not surveys, hence it doesn't seem logical to me... But maybe I'm overcomplicating this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the survey as the first class citizen, I would structure it like so

1. GET `/surveys`: Get all surveys
2. GET `/surveys/<surveyId>/questions`: Get questions for a survey.
3. GET `/surveys/<surveyId>/questions/<questionId>/answers`: Get answers for a survey question.
4. GET `/surveys/<surveyId>/reports`: Get report for a survey.

Note: If you think reports are going to be filtered by multiple paramaters, you could consider making it a search end point.

GET `/surveys/<surveyId>/reports?questionId=<questionId>`

Comment: I like it, looks very elegant. Do you know any good guides on how to determine first class citizens in such situations?

Comment: That's more to do with how you design your domain entities for the service you're building. For example, if you're designing an order management system, it's likely an `Order` is the first class citizen.

Comment: Also, here's a video you may find useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6CeaA-Phqo